# what is the exact syntax and semantics of a quoted string in the http1.1 rfc2616

Tags: http, rfc, rfc2616

In the [rfc2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) which is the HTTP/1.1 standard, a quoted string is defined as follows.

```
quoted-string  = ( <"> *(qdtext | quoted-pair ) <"> )
quoted-pair    = "\" CHAR
CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
qdtext         = <any TEXT except <">>
TEXT           = <any OCTET except CTLs, but including LWS>
```

With this definition "" seems to be a TEXT, and therefore `<">\<">` (quote, backslash, quote) seems to be a valid quoted string. But this contradicts the proper usage of backslash as escape character and can even lead to not unambiguously being able to determine the end of the quoted string. Where is my error here?

The RFC also states

```
LWS            = [CRLF] 1*( SP | HT )
All linear
white space, including folding, has the same semantics as SP. A
recipient MAY replace any linear white space with a single SP before
interpreting the field value or forwarding the message downstream.
```

I have read the interpretation that even LWS inside quoted strings can be replaced by SP. If I take the RFC literally that's what it says. I am puzzled by this, since this means the quoted strings " ", "\n ", "\n\t \t \t", … are all the same. Can those quoted strings really not be semantically distinguished?

Comment: For information, in case someone looks for the syntax of quoted string (or anything else), **the RFC2616 has been made obsolete by RFC7230-7235 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#History))**, and the one which contains the corrected `quoted-string` syntax is RFC7230.

Comment: And RFC7230 says it has been obsoleted by [RFC9110](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#quoted.strings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re question 1: It's a bug in the RFC.

See [HTTPbis WG ticket 31](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/31) and [HTTPbis, Part 1, Section 3.2.3](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-16.html#rfc.section.3.2.3).

Re question 2: see [HTTPbis Part 1, 3.2.1](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-16.html#rfc.section.3.2.1.p.3) - so no, you can't distinguish these.

Comment: This answers the escaping issue, what is with the LWS semantics question?

Comment: First, thanks for this Q&A, it helped me, and I [wrote a summary](https://evolvis.org/pipermail/evolvis-platfrm-discuss/2014-November/000675.html) at work. @johannes yes they cannot. You can backslash-escape all literal space and tab characters inside a quoted string, so `$'  \t'` becomes `$'\\ \\ \\\t'` (or, if you want a more visual representation, `··→` becomes `"\·\·\→"`), and newlines and other control characters are just lost.